# LRU Cache C++ Implementation

Tags: c++, caching

**Problem**

Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and set.

`get(key)` - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.

`set(key, value)` - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the least recently used item before inserting a new item.

**My program**

```
class LRUCache {
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity) {
        LRUCache::capacity = capacity;
        len = 0;
    }

    int get(int key) {
        if (table.find(key) != table.end()) {
            removeNode(table[key]);
            setHead(table[key]);
            return table[key]->value;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    void set(int key, int value) {
        if(table.find(key) != table.end()) {
            ListNode *curr = table[key];
            curr->value = value;
            removeNode(curr);
            setHead(curr);
        } else {
            ListNode *curr = new ListNode(key, value);
            if(len < capacity) {
                setHead(curr);
                table[key] = curr;
                len++;
            } else {
                ListNode *tmp = tail;
                tail = tail->prev;
                if(tail) {
                    tail->next = nullptr;
                }
                table.erase(tmp->key);
                delete tmp;
                setHead(curr);
                table[key] = curr;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    struct ListNode {
        int key, value;
        ListNode *prev, *next;
        ListNode(int key, int value)
            : key(key)
            , value(value)
            , prev(nullptr)
            , next(nullptr) {
        }

    };
    unordered_map<int, ListNode*> table;
    ListNode *head, *tail;
    int capacity;
    int len;
    void removeNode(ListNode *node) {
        if(node->prev) {
            node->prev->next = node->next;
        } else {
            head = node->next;
        }
        if(node->next) {
            node->next->prev = node->prev;
        } else {
            tail = node->prev;
        }
    }

    void setHead(ListNode *node) {
        node->next = head;
        node->prev = nullptr;
        if(head) {
            head->prev = node;
        }
        head = node;
        if(!tail) {
            tail = node;
        }
    }
};
```

Sample Input:

```
1 // capacity
2 1 // set(int, int)
1 // get(int)
```

Output in my machine:

**-1**

Output in online judge compiler:

**Runtime Error**

Whats wrong actually? [The problem is of Leetcode](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/).

Comment: Nor does asserting you *ran* it mean you *debugged* it. Is that the only data set you ran against it? (and I did read it, ex: the repeated unnecessary lookups via `operator[]` in `get()` are woefully inefficient). Where exactly, for example, do you initialize `head` and `tail` to NULL for your linked list?

Comment: yes. after initializing `head` and `tail`, its Accepted now. :) The weird thing is that without the initialization it was working perfectly against all testcases in my system

Comment: I suspect your debug-allocator zeros memory (a most non-helpful attribute imho when tracking down issues like this). Perhaps reroll this at some future time to use `std::list<>` for your values and map keys to iterators. Best of luck.

Comment: Are you sure everything after the *new* is none throwing? if you are try making a cache with size zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialise `head` and `tail`, so they have indeterminate values. If those values happen to be null, then the program will work as you expect; if not, anything could happen.

A runtime analysis tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is good for finding mistakes like this.

Comment: Ops! `LRUCache(int capacity) { LRUCache::capacity = capacity; len = 0; head = tail = nullptr;}` and now Accepted! Thanks Sir!

Comment: The weird thing is - it was working perfectly against all testcases in my system

Comment: @KaidulIslam: That can happen if memory happens to contain zero values, so the pointers are null by chance. That's the biggest problem with undefined behaviour: anything can happen.